# mobile web development tips

Tags: .net, mobile

I'm starting on creating a mobile version of one of our companies many web applications. We have a combination of mostly WebForms .NET and classic ASP sites.

I've looked around a bit and the JQueryMobile framework looks great for user 'mobile-izing' UI elements and transitions but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work well with WebForms development. Converting our existing sites to MVC isn't really an option. I guess one option would be to create the mobile versions using MVC but nobody in our company uses that technology so I hesitate to go down that road.

Are there any other software 'shortcuts' similar to JQueryMobile that might play a little nicer with WinForms development?

Sorry if this is a basic question but I'm starting from square one regarding the mobile web.

Answer (score 1):

Most mobile web application is essentially a simplified version of what you have currently. You should be able to use ASP.NET Web Forms for mobile. For code cleanliness, you may want to create a different ASPX file separate from your current pages.

There's more tricks (AJAX for smaller download sizes, one thing comes to mind) but you can learn it on the go.

Answer (score 0):

You can create web form application for mobile separately. Even with MVC, you have to create separate views in another area.

I would use Jquery mobile, and employ $.ajax and [WebMethod] to communicate between browser and web server in your web form application.